# RxJS - How Subscriber is different from Observable and Subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been trying to find an example of wrapping Observable into a Subscriber to monitor async call's status e.g. loading, completed or errored. Can you provide a short example?

Comment: Btw, this is 5000th question tagged as `rxjs` :).

Comment: Cool! Seems like today's my lucky day :).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can wrap an async http call like so

```
const httpStream = Observable.create(observer => {

    fetch('http://server.com')
      .then(response => response.json()) 
      .then(data => {
        observer.next(data); // if http call provides progress as well as completion
                             // these can all be pushed with observer.next()
        observer.complete();
      })
      .catch(err => observer.error(err));

  });

  httpStream.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Of course if it was actually fetch you wanted to wrap you could instead just do

```
var result = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://myserver.com/'));
```

**EDIT:** If you are using the angular HttpClient then there is no need to wrap it as it is already an observable. To get progress updates as well as the final response something like the following should work

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://api.server.com', body, {
    reportProgress: true
});

this._http.request(req)
.filter((event) => event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress || event instanceof HttpResponse)
.map((event) => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        return { type: 'uploadProgress', percentDone };
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        return { type: 'httpResponse', status: event.status };
    } 
})
.subscribe((response) => {
    if (response.type === 'uploadProgress') {
        console.log(`upload still in progress - percent done = ${response.percentDone}%`);
    } else {
        console.log(`upload completed  - status = ${response.status}`);
    }
});
```

If in fact all you want to know is when all the request have completed, and don't need the progress updates from each then rather than pushing the requests into an array a better option might be to use a forkJoin - which is similar to a promise.all in that you only get an output from the observable once all of the sub observables have completed - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: If I already have `let obs = http.get(); let sub = obs.subscribe()`. Will I still need to introduce a separate observer?

Comment: no, if you are already using the likes of Angular's http observable you don't need to wrap this in another observable. So are you just wanting to know how to use Angular's HttpClient to show details of progress and completion of an http call?

Comment: I want to monitor progress, but working on returned `obervable` or `subscription`, but not within actual calls. e.g. `subs.push(obs | sub)` and then working on `subs` array to show busy indicator if any element is in progress.